# Display multiple strings in a cell of a datatable that can be removed by clicking on them

Tags: r, shiny, dt, shinywidgets

I have the shiny app below in which I convert the `d` dataframe to a dataframe in which the unique `items` will be summarized based on the `name` and a new column will be added with their `count`. Then I use `DT` package to display this dataframe. I wonder if `DT` or `shinywidgets` or maybe another method can be used in order to display the table like in the screenshot below in which the user will be able to display the different strings in the `items` column as separated words that he will be able to remove. Here is an example in the second column.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(jsonlite)

selector <- function(id, values, items = values){
  options <- HTML(paste0(mapply(
    function(value, item){
      as.character(tags$option(value = value, item))
    }, c("", values), c("", items)
  ), collapse = ""))
  as.character(
    tags$select(
      id = id, class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple", options
    )
  )
}

name<-c("Jack","Bob","Jack","Bob")
item<-c("apple","olive","banana","tomato")
d<-data.frame(name,item)

words<-tapply(d$item, d$name, I)


nrows <- length(words)

js <- c(
  "function(settings) {",
  sprintf("var nrows = %d;", nrows),
  sprintf("var words = %s;", toJSON(words)),
  "  var table = this.api().table();",
  "  function selectize(i) {",
  "    $('#slct' + i).selectize({",
  "      items: words[i-1],",
  "      onChange: function(value) {",
  "        table.cell(i-1, 2).data(value.length);",
  "      }",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "  for(var i = 1; i <= nrows; i++) {",
  "    selectize(i);",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('slct' + i, words[i-1]);",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("table"),
  div( # this is a hidden selectize input whose role is to make
    # available 'selectize.js'
    style = "display: none;",
    selectInput("id", "label", c("x", "y"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    dat <- data.frame(
      FOO = c(unique(d$name)),
      Words = vapply(
        1:nrows,
        function(i){
          selector(paste0("slct", i), words[[i]])
        },
        character(1)
      ),
      Count = lengths(words),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    
    datatable(
      data = dat,
      selection = "none",
      escape = FALSE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      options = list(
        initComplete = JS(js),
        preDrawCallback = JS(
          'function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'
        ),
        drawCallback = JS(
          'function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'
        )
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do that with a `selectizeInput`:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

js <- c(
  "function(settings){",
  "  $('#mselect').selectize();",
  "}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("table"),
  div(
    style = "display: none;",
    selectInput("id", "label", c("x", "y"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    dat <- data.frame(
      FOO = "bar",
      BAZ = '<select id="mselect" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
                       <option value=""></option>
                       <option value="A">Apple</option>
                       <option value="B">Banana</option>
                       <option value="C">Lemon</option>
                       </select>',
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    
    datatable(
      data = dat,
      selection = "none",
      escape = FALSE,
      rownames = FALSE, 
      options = list(
        initComplete = JS(js)
      )
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## EDIT

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

selector <- function(id, values, items = values){
  options <- HTML(paste0(mapply(
    function(value, item){
      as.character(tags$option(value = value, item))
    }, c("",values), c("",items)
  ), collapse = ""))
  as.character(
    tags$select(
      id = id, class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple", options
    )
  )
}

words1 <- c("apple", "banana")
words2 <- c("olive", "tomato")

js <- c(
  "function(settings) {",
  sprintf("var words1 = [%s];", toString(shQuote(words1))),
  sprintf("var words2 = [%s];", toString(shQuote(words2))),
  "  $('#slct1').selectize({items: words1});",
  "  $('#slct2').selectize({items: words2});",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('slct1', words1);",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('slct2', words2);",
  "}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("words1"),
  DTOutput("table"),
  div( # this is a hidden selectize input whose role is to make
       # available 'selectize.js'
    style = "display: none;",
    selectInput("id", "label", c("x", "y"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    dat <- data.frame(
      FOO = c("bar", "baz"),
      Words = c(
        selector("slct1", words1),
        selector("slct2", words2)
      ),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )

    datatable(
      data = dat,
      selection = "none",
      escape = FALSE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      options = list(
        initComplete = JS(js),
        preDrawCallback = JS(
          'function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'
        ),
        drawCallback = JS(
          'function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'
        )
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)

  output[["words1"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["slct1"]]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## EDIT

With the counts:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

selector <- function(id, values, items = values){
  options <- HTML(paste0(mapply(
    function(value, item){
      as.character(tags$option(value = value, item))
    }, c("",values), c("",items)
  ), collapse = ""))
  as.character(
    tags$select(
      id = id, class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple", options
    )
  )
}

words1 <- c("apple", "banana")
words2 <- c("olive", "tomato")

js <- c(
  "function(settings) {",
  sprintf("var words1 = [%s];", toString(shQuote(words1))),
  sprintf("var words2 = [%s];", toString(shQuote(words2))),
  "  var table = this.api().table();",
  "  $('#slct1').selectize({",
  "    items: words1,",
  "    onChange: function(value) {",
  "      var count = value.length;",
  "      table.cell(0,2).data(count);",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "  $('#slct2').selectize({",
  "    items: words2,",
  "    onChange: function(value) {",
  "      var count = value.length;",
  "      table.cell(1,2).data(count);",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('slct1', words1);",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('slct2', words2);",
  "}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("words1"),
  DTOutput("table"),
  div( # this is a hidden selectize input whose role is to make
       # available 'selectize.js'
    style = "display: none;",
    selectInput("id", "label", c("x", "y"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    dat <- data.frame(
      FOO = c("bar", "baz"),
      Words = c(
        selector("slct1", words1),
        selector("slct2", words2)
      ),
      Count = c(length(words1), length(words2)),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )

    datatable(
      data = dat,
      selection = "none",
      escape = FALSE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      options = list(
        initComplete = JS(js),
        preDrawCallback = JS(
          'function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'
        ),
        drawCallback = JS(
          'function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'
        )
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)

  output[["words1"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["slct1"]]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

---

## EDIT

For an arbitrary number of rows:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(jsonlite)

selector <- function(id, values, items = values){
  options <- HTML(paste0(mapply(
    function(value, item){
      as.character(tags$option(value = value, item))
    }, c("", values), c("", items)
  ), collapse = ""))
  as.character(
    tags$select(
      id = id, class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple", options
    )
  )
}

words <- list(
  c("apple", "banana"),
  c("olive", "tomato")
)

nrows <- length(words)

js <- c(
  "function(settings) {",
  sprintf("var nrows = %d;", nrows),
  sprintf("var words = %s;", toJSON(words)),
  "  var table = this.api().table();",
  "  function selectize(i) {",
  "    $('#slct' + i).selectize({",
  "      items: words[i-1],",
  "      onChange: function(value) {",
  "        table.cell(i-1, 2).data(value.length);",
  "      }",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "  for(var i = 1; i <= nrows; i++) {",
  "    selectize(i);",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('slct' + i, words[i-1]);",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("words1"),
  DTOutput("table"),
  div( # this is a hidden selectize input whose role is to make
       # available 'selectize.js'
    style = "display: none;",
    selectInput("id", "label", c("x", "y"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    dat <- data.frame(
      FOO = c("bar", "baz"),
      Words = vapply(
        1:nrows,
        function(i){
          selector(paste0("slct", i), words[[i]])
        },
        character(1)
      ),
      Count = lengths(words),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )

    datatable(
      data = dat,
      selection = "none",
      escape = FALSE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      options = list(
        initComplete = JS(js),
        preDrawCallback = JS(
          'function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'
        ),
        drawCallback = JS(
          'function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'
        )
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)

  output[["words1"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["slct1"]]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks but Im not sure how to pass my dataframe d in there since you pass the options manually. My original dataset d is much bigger I cannot pass every option manually

Comment: wow that is more than a full answer I ll give that to you ana continue my work based on your answer thanks

Comment: hey I had adapted a little bit the list I m using in your answer and now I get numbers instead of names and also the selectize inputs seem to be empty.

Comment: I have created a new Q based on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65668902/datatable-displays-numbers-instead-of-characters-coming-from-a-list-in-a-shiny-a

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version. It uses the JavaScript library **select2** instead of **selectize**. I find this one more convenient for the removal of the selected options: they are removed on clicking, while with **selectize** one needs the keyboard to remove an option.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

selector <- function(id, values, items = values){
  options <- HTML(paste0(mapply(
    function(value, item){
      as.character(tags$option(value = value, selected = "selected", item))
    }, values, items
  ), collapse = ""))
  as.character(
    tags$select(
      id = id, multiple = "multiple", options
    )
  )
}

words <- list(
  c("apple", "banana"),
  c("olive", "tomato")
)
nrows <- length(words)

js <- c(
  "function(settings) {",
  sprintf("var nrows = %d;", nrows),
  "  var table = this.api().table();",
  "  function selectize(i) {",
  "    var $slct = $('#slct' + i);",
  "    $slct.select2({",
  "      width: '100%',",
  "      closeOnSelect: false",
  "    });",
  "    $slct.on('change', function(e) {",
  "      table.cell(i-1, 2).data($slct.val().length);",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "  for(var i = 1; i <= nrows; i++) {",
  "    selectize(i);",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js")
  ),
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("words1"),
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    dat <- data.frame(
      FOO = c("bar", "baz"),
      Words = vapply(
        1:nrows,
        function(i){
          selector(paste0("slct", i), words[[i]])
        },
        character(1)
      ),
      Count = lengths(words),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )

    datatable(
      data = dat,
      selection = "none",
      escape = FALSE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      options = list(
        initComplete = JS(js),
        preDrawCallback = JS(
          'function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'
        ),
        drawCallback = JS(
          'function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'
        )
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)

  output[["words1"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["slct1"]]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: based on your solution I developed this app and Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65693747/add-a-new-row-to-a-dataframe-by-clicking-on-a-datatable-row-and-actionbutton

Comment: Hi Stephane based on your code I try to implemet 2 more features. I think you re the only one that can help me to finish this since this your method. In the 1st one u need to apply the method in the next DT row https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712967/move-to-the-next-row-of-clicked-one-in-a-dt-datatable-using-an-actionbutton and in the 2nd to another DT row https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65710169/assign-a-value-on-a-different-row-of-a-datatable-than-the-clicked-one-in-a-shiny