# Add a new row to a dataframe by clicking on a datatable row and actionbutton

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have the shiny app and the dataframes below.

When I click on a row I get a text which displays the similarity of this `attribute_name` with a .

If I click `Next` I get the similarity of the same `attribute_name` with the next `candidate_2`.

I want to be able to press the `Add` `actionbutton()` and add this `candidate_2` to the related `selectInput()` in the table.

For example if I click on the 1st row of the table and press `Add` the word `micro` will be added in the `selectInput()` of the first row.

Basically what needed is to add a new row to the dataframe `d` everytime I select a row and press the `Add` `actionbutton()`.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)

attribute_name <- c("Jack", "Bob", "Jack", "Bob")
category_id <- c(7, 7, 7, 7)
candidate_phrase_lemma <- c("apple", "olive", "banana", "tomato")
d <- data.frame(
  attribute_name,
  category_id,
  candidate_phrase_lemma,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
names <- tapply(d$candidate_phrase_lemma, d$attribute_name, I)

candidate_1 <- c("Jack", "Bob", "Jack", "Bob")
candidate_2 <- c("phone", "camera", "micro", "pc")
similarity <- c(4, 5, 6, 7)
category_id <- c(7, 7, 7, 7)
e <- data.frame(candidate_1, candidate_2, similarity, category_id)

selector <- function(id, values, items = values) {
  options <- HTML(paste0(mapply(
    function(value, item) {
      as.character(tags$option(value = value, selected = "selected", item))
    }, values, items
  ), collapse = ""))
  as.character(
    tags$select(
      id = id, multiple = "multiple", options
    )
  )
}

nrows <- length(names)

initComplete <- c(
  "function(settings) {",
  sprintf("var nrows = %d;", nrows),
  "  var table = this.api().table();",
  "  function selectize(i) {",
  "    var $slct = $('#slct' + i);",
  "    $slct.select2({",
  "      width: '100%',",
  "      closeOnSelect: false",
  "    });",
  "    $slct.on('change', function(e) {",
  "      table.cell(i-1, 2).data($slct.val().length);",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "  for(var i = 1; i <= nrows; i++) {",
  "    selectize(i);",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

js <- paste0(c(
  "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler(",
  "  'addCandidate',",
  "  function(row_candidate) {",
  "    var i = row_candidate.row;",
  "    var candidate = row_candidate.candidate;",
  "    var $slct = $('#slct' + i);",
  "    if($slct.find(\"option[value='\" + candidate + \"']\").length === 0) {",
  "      var newOption = new Option(candidate, candidate, true, true);",
  "      $slct.append(newOption).trigger('change');",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  ");"
), collapse = "\n")

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css"),
      tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"),
      tags$style(HTML(
        ".select2-selection__choice {background-color: darkblue !important;}"
      )),
      tags$script(HTML(js))
    ),
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      DTOutput("table"),
      textOutput("celltext"),
      fluidRow(
        column(1, actionButton("dec", "Next")),
        column(1, actionButton("bc", "Back")),
        column(1, actionButton("addWord", "Add"))
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    Text <- reactiveVal()
    Data <- reactiveVal()
    Candidate <- reactiveVal()
    rnum <- reactiveVal(0)
    rnumm <- reactiveVal(0)
    
    output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
      dat <- data.frame(
        attributes = unique(as.character(d$attribute_name)),
        attributes_phrases = vapply(
          1:nrows,
          function(i) {
            selector(paste0("slct", i), names[[i]])
          },
          character(1)
        ),
        Count = lengths(names),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      )
      datatable(
        data = dat,
        selection = list(target = "row", mode = "single"),
        escape = FALSE,
        rownames = FALSE,
        options = list(
          pageLength = 5,
          initComplete = JS(initComplete),
          preDrawCallback = JS(
            "function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }"
          ),
          drawCallback = JS(
            "function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); }"
          )
        )
      )
    }, server = FALSE)
    
    
    observeEvent(input[["table_rows_selected"]], {
      row <- input[["table_rows_selected"]]
      dat <- e[e[["candidate_1"]] %in% d[row, 1], ]
      Data(dat[order(dat[["similarity"]], decreasing = TRUE), ])
      Candidate(Data()[1, 2])
      Text(
        paste(
          "Similarity of", Data()[1, 1], 
          "to candidate", Candidate(), 
          "is", Data()[1, 3]
        )
      )
      rnum(1)
      rnumm(nrow(dat))
      output[["celltext"]] <- renderText({
        if (length(input[["table_rows_selected"]])) {
          Text()
        } else {
          ""
        }
      })
    })
    observeEvent(input[["dec"]], {
      if (rnum() < rnumm()) rnum(rnum() + 1)
      Candidate(Data()[rnum(), 2])
      Text(
        paste(
          "Similarity of", Data()[rnum(), 1], 
          "to candidate", Candidate(), 
          "is", Data()[rnum(), 3])
      )
    })
    observeEvent(input[["bc"]], {
      if (rnum() < rnumm()) rnum(rnum() - 1)
      Candidate(Data()[rnum(), 2])
      Text(
        paste(
          "Similarity of", Data()[rnum(), 1], 
          "to candidate", Candidate(), 
          "is", Data()[rnum(), 3])
      )
    })
    observeEvent(input[["addWord"]], {
      session$sendCustomMessage(
        "addCandidate",
        list(row = input[["table_rows_selected"]], candidate = Candidate())
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice app. Below is my solution. I don't add a new row to the dataframe; I directly add an item to the select input via JavaScript.

[image]

```r
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)

attribute_name <- c("Jack", "Bob", "Jack", "Bob")
category_id <- c(7, 7, 7, 7)
candidate_phrase_lemma <- c("apple", "olive", "banana", "tomato")
d <- data.frame(
  attribute_name,
  category_id,
  candidate_phrase_lemma,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
names <- tapply(d$candidate_phrase_lemma, d$attribute_name, I)

candidate_1 <- c("Jack", "Bob", "Jack", "Bob")
candidate_2 <- c("phone", "camera", "micro", "pc")
similarity <- c(4, 5, 6, 7)
category_id <- c(7, 7, 7, 7)
e <- data.frame(candidate_1, candidate_2, similarity, category_id)

selector <- function(id, values, items = values) {
  options <- HTML(paste0(mapply(
    function(value, item) {
      as.character(tags$option(value = value, selected = "selected", item))
    }, values, items
  ), collapse = ""))
  as.character(
    tags$select(
      id = id, multiple = "multiple", options
    )
  )
}

nrows <- length(names)

initComplete <- c(
  "function(settings) {",
  sprintf("var nrows = %d;", nrows),
  "  var table = this.api().table();",
  "  function selectize(i) {",
  "    var $slct = $('#slct' + i);",
  "    $slct.select2({",
  "      width: '100%',",
  "      closeOnSelect: false",
  "    });",
  "    $slct.on('change', function(e) {",
  "      table.cell(i-1, 2).data($slct.val().length);",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "  for(var i = 1; i <= nrows; i++) {",
  "    selectize(i);",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

js <- paste0(c(
  "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler(",
  "  'addCandidate',",
  "  function(row_candidate) {",
  "    var i = row_candidate.row;",
  "    var candidate = row_candidate.candidate;",
  "    var $slct = $('#slct' + i);",
  "    if($slct.find(\"option[value='\" + candidate + \"']\").length === 0) {",
  "      var newOption = new Option(candidate, candidate, true, true);",
  "      $slct.append(newOption).trigger('change');",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  ");"
), collapse = "\n")

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css"),
      tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"),
      tags$style(HTML(
        ".select2-selection__choice {background-color: darkblue !important;}"
      )),
      tags$script(HTML(js))
    ),
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      DTOutput("table"),
      textOutput("celltext"),
      fluidRow(
        column(1, actionButton("dec", "Next")),
        column(1, actionButton("addWord", "Add"))
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    Text <- reactiveVal()
    Data <- reactiveVal()
    Candidate <- reactiveVal()
    rnum <- reactiveVal(0)
    rnumm <- reactiveVal(0)
    
    output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
      dat <- data.frame(
        attributes = unique(as.character(d$attribute_name)),
        attributes_phrases = vapply(
          1:nrows,
          function(i) {
            selector(paste0("slct", i), names[[i]])
          },
          character(1)
        ),
        Count = lengths(names),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      )
      datatable(
        data = dat,
        selection = list(target = "row", mode = "single"),
        escape = FALSE,
        rownames = FALSE,
        options = list(
          pageLength = 5,
          initComplete = JS(initComplete),
          preDrawCallback = JS(
            "function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }"
          ),
          drawCallback = JS(
            "function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); }"
          )
        )
      )
    }, server = FALSE)
    
    
    observeEvent(input[["table_rows_selected"]], {
      row <- input[["table_rows_selected"]]
      dat <- e[e[["candidate_1"]] %in% d[row, 1], ]
      Data(dat[order(dat[["similarity"]], decreasing = TRUE), ])
      Candidate(Data()[1, 2])
      Text(
        paste(
          "Similarity of", Data()[1, 1], 
          "to candidate", Candidate(), 
          "is", Data()[1, 3]
        )
      )
      rnum(1)
      rnumm(nrow(dat))
      output[["celltext"]] <- renderText({
        if (length(input[["table_rows_selected"]])) {
          Text()
        } else {
          ""
        }
      })
    })
    observeEvent(input[["dec"]], {
      if (rnum() < rnumm()) rnum(rnum() + 1)
      Candidate(Data()[rnum(), 2])
      Text(
        paste(
          "Similarity of", Data()[rnum(), 1], 
          "to candidate", Candidate(), 
          "is", Data()[rnum(), 3])
      )
    })
    observeEvent(input[["addWord"]], {
      session$sendCustomMessage(
        "addCandidate",
        list(row = input[["table_rows_selected"]], candidate = Candidate())
      )
    })
  }
)
```

## EDIT: styling suggestion

[image]

```r
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css"),
      tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"),
      tags$style(HTML(
        ".select2-selection__choice {background-color: darkblue !important;}"
      )),
      tags$script(HTML(js))
    ),
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      DTOutput("table"),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.table_rows_selected.length > 0",
        wellPanel(
          uiOutput("celltext"),
          splitLayout(
          actionButton("dec", "Next candidate"),
          actionButton("addWord", "Add this candidate"),
          cellWidths = "fit-content"
        )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    Text <- reactiveVal()
    Data <- reactiveVal()
    Candidate <- reactiveVal()
    rnum <- reactiveVal(0)
    rnumm <- reactiveVal(0)
    
    output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
      dat <- data.frame(
        attributes = unique(as.character(d$attribute_name)),
        attributes_phrases = vapply(
          1:nrows,
          function(i) {
            selector(paste0("slct", i), names[[i]])
          },
          character(1)
        ),
        Count = lengths(names),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      )
      datatable(
        data = dat,
        selection = list(target = "row", mode = "single"),
        escape = FALSE,
        rownames = FALSE,
        options = list(
          pageLength = 5,
          initComplete = JS(initComplete),
          preDrawCallback = JS(
            "function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }"
          ),
          drawCallback = JS(
            "function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); }"
          )
        )
      )
    }, server = FALSE)
    
    
    observeEvent(input[["table_rows_selected"]], {
      row <- input[["table_rows_selected"]]
      dat <- e[e[["candidate_1"]] %in% d[row, 1], ]
      Data(dat[order(dat[["similarity"]], decreasing = TRUE), ])
      Candidate(Data()[1, 2])
      Text(
        paste(
          "Similarity of <em>", Data()[1, 1], "</em>", 
          "to candidate <em>", Candidate(), "</em>", 
          "is <strong>", Data()[1, 3], "</strong>"
        )
      )
      rnum(1)
      rnumm(nrow(dat))
      output[["celltext"]] <- renderUI({
        if (length(input[["table_rows_selected"]])) {
          HTML(Text())
        } else {
          ""
        }
      })
    })
    observeEvent(input[["dec"]], {
      if (rnum() < rnumm()) rnum(rnum() + 1)
      Candidate(Data()[rnum(), 2])
      Text(
        paste(
          "Similarity of <em>", Data()[rnum(), 1], "</em>", 
          "to candidate <em>", Candidate(), "</em>",
          "is <strong>", Data()[rnum(), 3], "</strong>"
        )
      )
    })
    observeEvent(input[["addWord"]], {
      session$sendCustomMessage(
        "addCandidate",
        list(row = input[["table_rows_selected"]], candidate = Candidate())
      )
    })
  }
)
```

---

## EDIT

Regarding your comment, here is the app with a simplified server logic and the back/next buttons are disabled when needed:

```
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css"),
      tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"),
      tags$style(HTML(
        ".select2-selection__choice {background-color: darkblue !important;}"
      )),
      tags$script(HTML(js))
    ),
    useShinyjs(),
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      DTOutput("table"),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.table_rows_selected.length > 0",
        wellPanel(
          uiOutput("celltext"),
          splitLayout(
            actionButton("bc", "Previous candidate"),
            actionButton("dec", "Next candidate"),
            actionButton("addWord", "Add this candidate", class = "btn-info"),
            cellWidths = "fit-content"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    Text <- reactiveVal()
    Data <- reactiveVal()
    Candidate <- reactiveVal()
    rnum <- reactiveVal()

    output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
      dat <- data.frame(
        attributes = unique(as.character(d$attribute_name)),
        attributes_phrases = vapply(
          1:nrows,
          function(i) {
            selector(paste0("slct", i), names[[i]])
          },
          character(1)
        ),
        Count = lengths(names),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      )
      datatable(
        data = dat,
        selection = list(target = "row", mode = "single"),
        escape = FALSE,
        rownames = FALSE,
        options = list(
          pageLength = 5,
          initComplete = JS(initComplete),
          preDrawCallback = JS(
            "function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }"
          ),
          drawCallback = JS(
            "function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); }"
          )
        )
      )
    }, server = FALSE)
    
    
    observeEvent(input[["table_rows_selected"]], {
      row <- input[["table_rows_selected"]]
      dat <- e[e[["candidate_1"]] %in% d[row, 1], ]
      Data(dat[order(dat[["similarity"]], decreasing = TRUE), ])
      rnum(1)
    })
    output[["celltext"]] <- renderUI({
      HTML(Text())
    })
    observeEvent(input[["dec"]], {
      rnum(rnum() + 1)
    })
    observeEvent(input[["bc"]], {
      rnum(rnum() - 1)
    })
    observeEvent(list(rnum(), Data()), {
      if(rnum() == 1){
        disable("bc")
      }else{
        enable("bc")
      }
      if(rnum() == nrows){
        disable("dec")
      }else{
        enable("dec")
      }
      Candidate(Data()[rnum(), 2])
      Text(
        paste(
          "Similarity of <em>", Data()[rnum(), 1], "</em>",
          "to candidate <em>", Candidate(), "</em>",
          "is <strong>", Data()[rnum(), 3], "</strong>"
        )
      )
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    observeEvent(input[["addWord"]], {
      session$sendCustomMessage(
        "addCandidate",
        list(row = input[["table_rows_selected"]], candidate = Candidate())
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, just a small detail. Besides the Next button I also had a Back button which was tracking the previous word. I had not put it in order to provide minimal code. The issue with that is that now when there is no previous word it keeps going back while normally it should stop when its in the 1st word and display the last valid message. The same logic was applied for the Next button as well when it reaches the last word. I edited based on your solution.

Comment: I get an error Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  "fit-content" is not a valid CSS unit (e.g., "100%", "400px", "auto") Could you adapt to the version that I used in my edit cause that was the working one.

Comment: @firmo23 This is a new feature of the `htmltools` package - you have to upgrade it.

Comment: I have htmltools_0.5.1 installed but still getting Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argument is not a character vector

Comment: @firmo23 Hmm.. This error is possibly thrown by the `HTML` function when `Text()` is `NULL` (I have the development version of `htmltools` prior to 0.5.1). This is a guess. Could you try to replace `Text <- reactiveVal()` with `Text <- reactiveVal("")`.

Comment: I have replaced all reactiveVal() with reactiveVal("") but the error still exists

Comment: ok I got this but based on your non stylish solution thanks

Comment: I added a new button based on your solution here could you check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65710169/assign-a-value-on-a-different-row-of-a-datatable-than-the-clicked-one-in-a-shiny

Comment: and a different one here as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712967/move-to-the-next-row-of-clicked-one-in-a-dt-datatable-using-an-actionbutton